# Adding custom parameters to Azure Blob SAS

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to add a custom parameter to Azure Blob's SAS from

> sv=2019-07-07&st=2020-06-04T16%3A47%3A28Z&se=2020-06-04T16%3A52%3A28Z&sr=b&sp=w&sig=%2BtkPniCpScXJVeLEmSSFH%2FlzoOZLir1CVw2cy9Rh4fE%3D

to

> sv=2019-07-07&st=2020-06-04T16%3A47%3A28Z&se=2020-06-04T16%3A52%3A28Z&sr=b&sp=w&**hello=bye**&sig=%2BtkPniCpScXJVeLEmSSFH%2FlzoOZLir1CVw2cy9Rh4fE%3D

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters of sas token are pre-defined, you should exactly follow it's format to build sas token. So customized parameter is not allowed.

For the pre-defined parameter, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#specifying-the-signed-version-field).